# Limit number of items array includes

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, include

I have the following code that includes all the php files in a folder and includes them in a logical ascending order. I want to limit the number of files it includes to 4 but I am not sure what in my code to change or add.

How can I limit the code to include only the first 4 php files and leave the rest.

```
<?php

$events = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/overview/*.php");

if(count($events)) {
natcasesort($events);

foreach($events as $event) {
    $event = basename($event);


include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/overview/$event");

      }

    }

else {

echo "Sorry, no upcoming events.";

}

?>
```

Comment: A counter? [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)?

Comment: why have I been marked down for such an innocent honest question? :S Thanks for all answers. You have been a great help in my educational learning curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i=0;
foreach($events as $event) {
if($i > 3) {
    break;
}
$event = basename($event);
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/overview/$event");
$i++;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter

```
var count = 0;
foreach($events as $event) {
    $event = basename($event);
    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/overview/$event");
    count++;
    if(count>=4)
        break;
}
```

Or

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $event = basename($events[$i]);
    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/overview/$event");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a counter should do

```
$i++; 
if($i>4) 
    break;
```